# Fixed Header and Footer with auto height for slider in middle

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a website that has a fixed header and footer and for the entire middle to be an image slider....So its just a full browser website. For some reason I can not get the image to fill the entire content I am also trying to make it responsive which doesn't seem to work either. Would I need to use javascript to detect the browser height so I can fit the image to it or is there a plug in? I've been mostly trying to do it with CSS with height:100% then bringing in the padding on the top and bottom.

Here is the layout I am trying to create:
http://jsfiddle.net/PV6sE

```
<header>
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
</header>
<div class="banner"></div>
<footer></footer>
```

Any help would be appreciated! I've been stuck on this for hours!

Comment: Sorry about that! Copied the wrong link!

Comment: So to clarify, you want 100% height NOT 100% width? The difference being a narrow window wouldn't cover the bottom with 100% width. On the other hand with a 'short' but wide window, what would you like to do? Leave the sides white? Also, your jsfiddle has jQuery included, does that mean we can use jQuery code?

Comment: I would actually like the width and the height be full... I know that would cut off some of the image to get the ratios correct. jQuery is fine to use and preferred. I was playing around with jsfiddle before I posted and must've left it on.

Comment: Can you let me know if this is what you were looking for, and I'll explain it in an answer if it is. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GrahamW0009/PV6sE/1/)

Comment: Almost! Instead of the images scrolling down they just need to slide over the other one or fade out into the other image. Trying to build it so the website wont scroll at all...

Comment: Not sure I understand what will trigger the image change? Or do you want the change to be timed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the JavaScript which resized the image to the full size:

Note the 180 = the height of the header and footer combined.

```
window.onload = window.onresize = function () {
    $('img').each(function () {
        this.style.width = '100%';
        this.style.height = '';

        if (this.clientHeight < $(window).height() - 180) {
            this.style.width = '';
            this.style.height = $(window).height() - 180;
        }

        $(this).parent().css('height', $(window).height() - 180);

    });
};
```

And Here's the code for the slideshow:

```
var interval = 2500;
var array = $($('.banner li').get().reverse());
setInterval(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        $(array[i]).delay(interval * (i + 1)).fadeOut(300);
        $(array[i]).delay((interval-100) * (array.length - 1 - i)).fadeIn();
    }
}, interval*array.length);
```

The only change I made to your HTML was I changed `<div class="banner"></div>` to a `ul`.

Here's your updated CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header {
    top: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100000;
}
footer {
    background-color: blue;
    bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    height: 71px;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100000;
}
.top {
    background-color:#964B2D;
    height: 38px;
}
.bottom {
    background-color:red;
    height: 71px;
}

.banner {
    position: relative;
    margin: 109px 0 71px 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.banner li {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here's a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GrahamWalters/PV6sE/4/).

Comment: This is awesome! I think the problem I kept running into was subtracting 180. I didn't think of combining them and just pushing it down with margin. Thanks for your help! It was driving me crazy!

Comment: ahh yeah, if you think those values could change, you could use `var offset = $('header').height() + $('footer').height();` but I recommend using IDs instead of `header` and `footer`.